# How can I see the screenshots in Selendroid inspector?

Tags: selenium, selendroid

I am trying to learn Selendroid but have hit a road block. When I run the sample test (in python). I get the following error in the server log:

```
Jul 31, 2018 11:20:14 PM io.selendroid.standalone.server.handler.InspectorScreenshotHandler handleRequest
SEVERE: Cannot take screenshot for inspector
io.selendroid.standalone.exceptions.AndroidDeviceException: Device not accessible via ddmlib.
```

And when accessing the Selendroid inspector in the browser, there is now screenshot shown, it is like a missing resource.

Is there a way around this? The documentation has an advanced guide but only links to a blank page at spring.io.

Is it possible to move foward without the inspector screenshots? or will it be super difficult / annoying to find my way around through xml only?